# How do I use switch with structs in C

Tags: c, struct, switch-statement

Hi I have the following code snippet from [here](https://github.com/4dsystems/ViSi-Genie-RaspPi-Demo-Calculator/blob/master/calculator.c):

```
void handleGenieEvent(struct genieReplyStruct *reply) {
    if (reply->cmd != GENIE_REPORT_EVENT) {
        printf("Invalid event from the display: 0x%02X\r\n", reply->cmd) ;
        return;
    }    
    /**/
    if (reply->object == GENIE_OBJ_KEYBOARD) {
        if (reply->index == 0)  // Only one keyboard
            calculatorKey(reply->data);
        else
            printf("Unknown keyboard: %d\n", reply->index);
    } else
    if (reply->object == GENIE_OBJ_WINBUTTON) {
        /**/
        if (reply->index == 1) {    // Clock button on main display
            //do smth
        } else
        if (reply->index == 2) {
            //do smth
        } else
        if (reply->index == 0) { // Calculator button on clock display
            //do smth
        } else
            printf("Unknown button: %d\n", reply->index);
    } else
        printf("Unhandled Event: object: %2d, index: %d data: %d [%02X %02X %04X]\r\n",
      reply->object, reply->index, reply->data, reply->object, reply->index, reply->data);
}
```

And I am wondering if it's possible to use switch here, especially for the `index`

I tried this:

```
switch (reply->index)
    case 0:
        //do smth
    case 1: 
        //do smth
    case 2: 
        //do smth
```

but that doesn't work.

Comment: How doesn't it work? Tell us what it does when you try that.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] with the changed code. If you have trouble with the C syntax, a book or tutorial will help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because post lacks the  relevant code posted here.

Comment: you were right, sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
switch (reply->index)
{
    case 0:
      //do smth
        break;
    case 1: 
     //do smth
        break;
    case 2: 
     //do smth
        break;
    default:
        printf("Unknown button: %d\n", reply->index);
        break;
}
```

will work.

Please note that your sample should check the `reply`-Pointer upon function entry:

```
void handleGenieEvent (struct genieReplyStruct *reply)
{
    if (NULL == reply)
    {
        // report error
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: indeed it works, so sorry ! no idea what mystery went on here.

Comment: Handling NULL pointers when they're not expected is bad practice. If `reply` isn't supposed to  be NULL but think you might pass NULL by mistake, just use `assert(reply != NULL);`.

Comment: ok and what if I just leave it out? I have a default statement there which should catch NULL right?

Comment: No. You must have the separate `if` at the top. The `switch` does `reply->index` which causes `reply` to be dereferenced. If `reply` is `NULL`, you'll segfault _before_ the body of the `switch` can be executed.

Comment: BTW, you can also replace your if/else ladder for `reply->object` with a `switch` as well

Comment: ok, but I'm wondering if that makes sense, I read somewhere that it only makes sense if you have 5 or more elements

Answer (score 1):

In this case you should use brackets and the break statement:

```
switch (reply->index){ <---bracket
    case 0:
        //do smth
        break;
    case 1: 
        //do smth
        break;
    case 2: 
        //do smth
        break;
}<---bracket
```

If you want the same funcitonality as the if-else code snippet above, you need the break statements. If you miss the breaks and got case 0 for example, case 1 and 2 will execute as well.

Comment: true, but isn't that what flederwiesel postet ?

Comment: ok thanks (which was helpful because my stuff didn't work because I forgot the breaks :D )